# Google Latitude API with objective c

Tags: objective-c, api, google-latitude

Is it possible to get your location data via google latitude within your objective-c application? If so, can someone post code, examples, etc?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete ObjC library with examples:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/latitude/libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the latitude api with objective-c

my loophole is to download NimbleKit, an extension of xcode 4. Nimble kit allows you to program in html, javascript, css and it will translate the code to work on ios.

If you set up a server with latitude working on it, and connect your ios app to the server with JSON or Ajax, which both work with nimblekit, not the standard xcode, you can use the latitude api with ios devices.